# Is it legal to open account and invest in my born country if I am currently working in Japan?

Tags: taxes, investing, japan, hong-kong, tax-residency

I have my identity and I am  able to open investment account (for ETF, stocks and FX) in Hong Kong.  I now  hold a working visa and work in Japan.

The tax rate is high in Japan and my Japanese is poor and I am not able to either read or speak it.

Since the the taxing system is totally different between Hong Kong and Japan, 
I wonder if I invest using my Hong Kong identity, will I violate some law in Japan?